# iOS View Size iPad

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, user-interface

I have a short question about the UIViews on iPad. I created a new view on top of the main view on a UIViewController and added constraints left, right, top and bottom with a value of 0 in order to cover the whole View.

After running the app and as expected, I got the grey view on top of the complete main view.

Strangely, I get different values for the frame width and height for both views, when I printed them to stdout:

Main View:
Width: 768.0, Height: 1024.0
Second View:
Width: 375.0, Height: 667.0

I do not understand, why these values are not equal, because both views have the same size when running and the grey second view is greater than a width of 375.

My main approach is to add a AVPlayerLayer as a background video on the second grey view. But when I do this, the video does not cover full screen, but instead it just covers 375x667.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var secondView: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        print("Main View:")
        print("Width: \(self.view.frame.width), Height: \(self.view.frame.height)")

        print("Second View:")
        print("Width: \(self.secondView.frame.width), Height: \(self.secondView.frame.height)")

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

}
```

[Simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5vZgI.png)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `viewDidLoad` runs before the view has attained its final size. The view *exists* at this point; it has *not* been laid out. That doesn't happen until `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.